# Should we answer questions that break the rules?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, proofreading

This questions ([Please test me for the english sentence](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/44897/please-test-me-for-the-english-sentence)) is the most recent example, but I've seen others.

It breaks the rules (in this case, off-topic because of editing/proofreading) and has received one vote-to-close. The sentence isn't that bad and would be a pretty quick fix--but should I?

I don't want to encourage a bad habit in the user, but I don't mind taking care of this quick edit. How strict should we be about these things?

Comment: Related discussion: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1236/9161

Comment: If you share the opinion that it isn't a good quality question, you should (in my opinion) help the author edit the question to make it better instead of answering it. There are many questions that are easy to answer, but aren't good quality questions that would be useful to other learners.

Comment: I remember the suggestion from 'area51' stage how to treat these: Since they are unlikely to help anyone in the future, close and delete them, but don't hurry with that - help the poor soul out of current pickle, and once they have their needed answer, clean up so that it doesn't clutter the list of answered questions forever.